# Await a task in OnBackButtonPressed and use its result to return in the method?

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, async-await

I am trying to show a dialog to the user when leaving a screen if there any any changes made in the screen (for example Settings screen). However. the DisplayAlert method requires awaiting in order to get the result which I need to use as a return value in the OnBackButtonPressed. I need to await the result of the dialog and then execute the rest of the OnBackButtonPressed method.

The code that I am trying to eventually execute should be similar to the code below:

```
public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{
    private TestViewModel _vm;

    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        _vm = new TestViewModel();
        BindingContext = _vm;
    }

    protected override bool OnBackButtonPressed()
    {
        if (_vm.IsUnchanged) return base.OnBackButtonPressed();

        var result = await DisplayAlert("Title", "Are you sure you want to leave the screen with unsave changes?", "Yes", "No");

        // returning false will exit the screen
        return !result;
    }
}

public class TestViewModel
{
    // this condition logic will evaluate if the user has made any changes to this screen and not saved them by pressing a "Save" button

    public bool IsUnchanged{ get; set; }

    public TestViewModel()
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: So accepted answer from duplicate question doesn't work?

Comment: No, it did not work in my case as I need to return the result of the dialog

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

1. On your override, return `true` always;
2. Call the `base.OnBackButtonPressed` after a positive answer.

This way:

```
protected override bool OnBackButtonPressed()
{
    if (_vm.Condition) return base.OnBackButtonPressed();

    DisplayAlert("Title", "Are you sure you want to leave the screen?", "Yes", "No")
        .ContinueWith(answer => 
        {
            if(answer.Result)
                base.OnBackButtonPressed(); // I'm not sure, but maybe you should wrap it on a 'BeginInvokeOnMainThread'
        });

    return true;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer but it did not work. The execution continues and the method returns "true" before the alert dialog is shown. What is needed here await execution logic until there is a response from the dialog

Comment: I'm sorry, I couldn't understand you. That was the goal of this code: to ignore the 'BackButtonPressed' event and wait for user confirmation. The method override would indeed end its execution. Where is in your code the 'logic' that must be executed?

Comment: That is quite alright. I probably did not explain it very well. Anyway, that "logic" is not implemented in this test project but eventually will check if the user has made any changes to the data displayed on the screen. If true the dialog must be shown OnBackButtonPressed :)

Comment: So the `Condition` in your code is not supposed to be a property, but a method with that logic, is it right?

Comment: Yes, that would be right.

Comment: I'm unable to realize what's the matter of the issue. I'll wait for an edition on your question with a [mcve] and then I'll check again if I can help =). Good luck.

Comment: I changed the question's content. Hopefully now it makes more sense :)